# Final model for time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting, cross-validation, model-selection, model-evaluation

I am struggling with understanding how the final performance on an independent test set is obtained in a time series forecasting scenario.

My understanding is that rolling CV is used (as seen as in the picture) to prevent future datapoints to leak into the model. The ensemble of scores can than be used to deduce performance.

This method results in many models (in this case, four). What is the final model then selected for further use? Is it the final model, trained on most of the data? Is the performance of this model then described by the scores of the model itself, or by the ensemble of itself and all preceding models?

[image]

Comment: Thank you @RichardHardy, I am aware of how SE works but I am afraid the issue remains unclear for me. Ignoring hyperparameter tuning, would you agree the following is how CV is used for time series? (1) train a model on all data. (2) run a rolling CV where you, at each iteration, train a model and validate is on the respective sets as in the image. (3) the performance of the model from step 1 is said to be the average of all performances in step 2.

Comment: No, this is not how CV is used for time series. Step 1 is not taken. Step 2 is taken. The performance of the model is characterized by the union of the errors or losses from the different test sets. Summary measures such as the mean (over all the test sets) squared error are often used. The procedure above is carried out for a variety of candidate models. The model with the best performance is selected. That model is then reestimated on the entire dataset. It can then be used out of sample.

Comment: As I understand it we describe the same process, albeit my step 1 is your step 3. Whether the final model is trained before or after the CV would not matter, it might as well run in parallel.

Comment: What you call step 1 should be done for only one (the best) model out of all candidate models. Therefore, we need to do the other steps before it, as these other steps are required for selecting the best model. Doing it as step 1 means a bunch of unnecessary calculations. But this is not a big deal, really, if you are doing cross validation, as that is already quite costly. What seemed a bigger deal to me was to say *the performance of the model from step 1 is said to be the average of all performances in step 2.* But when I think about it again, this might be a matter of formulation.

Comment: I agree. However I also believe CV is not only needed when selecting a model or doing hyperparameter tuning, but also for getting a better estimate (read: reduce bias and variance) of the model performance when only a single model is used. If you add this to your answer I am happy to accept it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not have to result in 4 models. A common restriction is that the model is the same in all training samples, only its parameters are reestimated in each of them. The model is evaluated on a joint test set which is comprised of the four individual test sets.

If model selection needs to be done, the above is carried out for each model under consideration. The model that yields the best performance on the joint test set gets selected. The model's performance on the joint test set serves as an estimate of its performance on unseen future data. (The latter holds regardless of whether any model selection is going on at all.) The model's parameters are then reestimated on the entire data set, and genuine out-of-sample forecasting begins.

Comment: Perhaps there is some confusion on my end. When I look at the figure, I see four training sets. For each of these, I would imagine a model is trained on this data and validated on the corresponding test set. In my mind this results in four models. You say "[...] the model is the same in all training samples [...]", so then I wonder how this would work as there would be only a single instance of training. I worry this is a semantics issue on my end.

Comment: @TimStack, across the training sets, the model is the same up to parameter estimates. You estimate the model on four different training sets and test it on the corresponding test sets each time. You still consider this as one model. You do the same for all the different model specifications you have. You then select the best specification (based on the average performance across the four test sets) and proceed with it to real out-of-sample forecasting. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration Richard. I think it's a partial semantics issue since I don't consider two models trained on different data subsets as the same model. Could you clarify what you mean by "model specification"?

Comment: @TimStack, that must be it. Sorry for not being clearer about that. If you consider a parametric model, it consists of its functional form + parameter estimates such as [$y=X\beta+\varepsilon$] + [$\hat\beta=(1,2,3)'$]. What I mean by *specification* is the functional form $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$. The specification/form stays the same across the training samples, but the parameter estimates vary: in the first training sample we can have $\hat\beta^i=(1,2,3)'$, in the second $\hat\beta^{ii}=(1.5,1.5,2.5)'$, and so on. I call this the same model, albeit with different parameter estimates. Better?

Comment: Apologies for the struggles with terminology; studying at a uni does not expose you to too many variations of certain terms. As I understand it, the hyperparameters (part of the functional form) stay the same across the four samples, while the parameters (i.e. parameter estimates) change. Then it could be entirely possible the model/specification with the least data is deemed the best performer and used for actual forecasting. Could this not pose a problem, considering a lot of the data will be left unused?

Comment: Additionally, is the performance of this final model then validated on an independent test set or are the scores from the CV iteration used instead?

Comment: @TimStack, I do not understand *the model/specification with the least data*, as every specification (in my sense of the word) is tried out on the same data as any other specification. Re your second comment, if you have an independent test set, you can validate on it. If not, you are left with what you have from CV. If there has been some model selection, the CV performance of the best model will be an optimistic estimate of the true out-of-sample performance, and that should be kept in mind.